# Captcha control for .net 1.1

Tags: .net, captcha, asp.net-1.1

Please can anyone suggest good free solution for captcha in .net 1.1 ,

Please don't point me to google , asking for checked and tested by you solutions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used (it is independent from the serverside tech).

http://www.google.com/recaptcha/captcha